# In Swift how can I filter an array of objects conforming to a protocol by their class?

Tags: arrays, swift, class, functional-programming

I have a protocol, 'VariousThings', and two classes which conform to it, 'ThingType1' and 'ThingType2'. I've put some objects of these two types of classes into an array containing 'VariousThings'. I now want to just take all the objects out of that array that are of class type 'ThingType2' for example. How can I do this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
protocol VariousThings: class {

}

class ThingType1: VariousThings {

}

class ThingType2: VariousThings {

}


let array: [VariousThings] = [ThingType1(), ThingType2()]


func itemsMatchingType(type: VariousThings.Type) -> [VariousThings] {
    return array.filter { variousThing in
        return (variousThing.self === type)
    }
}


let justThingTypes1: [VariousThings] = itemsMatchingType(ThingType1)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap) instead of `filter` here in order to give you better type safety. You can use a conditional downcast to filter out the elements you want and generics in order to preserve type information. This takes advantage of the fact that `compactMap` can filter out `nil` results from the transform function.

```
let array: [VariousThings] = [ThingType1(), ThingType2()]    

func itemsMatchingType<T : VariousThings>(_ type: T.Type) -> [T] {
  return array.compactMap { $0 as? T }
}

let justThingTypes1 = itemsMatchingType(ThingType1.self) // of type [ThingType1]
```

Now the array you get out of your `itemsMatchingType` function is `[ThingType1]` if you pass in `ThingType1`, rather than simply `[VariousThings]`. That way you don't have to deal with ugly forced downcasts later down the line.

Comment: `.self` is actually not needed.

Comment: Good advice on the flatmap and returning T

Comment: @vadian True, although note that as of the latest version of Swift 3 (the one that ships with Xcode 8 beta 2), it'll generate a warning if you omit the `.self`.

Comment: As of Swift 4.1 (?), `flatMap` has to replaced by `compactMap`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generic

```
func itemsMatchingType<T : VariousThings>(type: T.Type) -> [VariousThings] {
  return array.filter { $0 is T }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `filter` for this:

```
let justThingsTypes1 = array.filter { $0 is ThingType1 }
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this method is that you *know* that the resulting array only has items of type `ThingType1`, but if the compiler is concerned, they just conform to `VariousTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let justThingTypes1: [VariousThings] = array.filter {
  variousThing in
  return Mirror(reflecting: variousThing).subjectType == ThingType1.self
}
```

Comment: It's better if you can explain what the solution does, rather than presenting it standalone. Then others will be able to understand your answer.